# how to customize popup window of available serial devices?

Tags: javascript, css, web, popupwindow, web-serial-api

I am using web serial API to communicate serial devices? when I click on connect button, there is the open window is open with available serial devices. so how can I customize this small window(link background-color, width, height, position, etc...).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can **not** update the style of the browser picker at the moment.

Comment: thanks for answering the question. but, why I cant update the style?

Comment: The browser doesn't let you do that. The same way you can't customize a `window.alert()` window.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't (currently) a way to modify it.

This is one of the browser special permissions dialogs (See https://permission.site/ for more). I believe it is vital that these dialogs cannot be forged or be misleading to maintain trust with the users- although I wasn't able to find anything in the spec calling this out.

I first recall this being discussed around the [Permissions API](https://w3c.github.io/permissions/#requesting-more-permission)- however I only could find this note:

> NOTE
> This is intentionally vague about the details of the permission UI and
> how the user agent infers user intent. User agents should be able to
> explore lots of UI within this framework.